# Access global variables in setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to generate some random-ish numbers and inside that function I make a call to setInterval() because I need those numbers to refresh every 2 seconds.

```
function genSine(val1, val2) {

    var freq = 0.1; // angular frequency

    var coords = function(x, y) {
        var amplitude = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        var phase = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
        return {
            x : Math.sin(freq * (val1 + phase) * amplitude) + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1),
            y : Math.sin(freq * (val2 + phase) * amplitude) + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
        };
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        current = coords(50, 50);
        console.log('Val 1: ' + current.x);
        console.log('Val 2: ' + current.y);
    }, 2000);
}

genSine(10, 20);
```

This is all well and good, the values update as expected but my goal is to have two global variables (let's call them val1/val2) update within that setInterval() function.  It appears I have a scoping issue because those variables are not accessible within the function and I can not access the 'current' variable from outside that function.  I know I am missing something here, what is it?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/niczak/4uNen/1/

Comment: declare `var current = {};` outside the function

Comment: here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4uNen/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define `var current = {};` in the global scope, and be sure *not* to define `var current` in any other scope. `current=[whatever];` is fine, as long as there's no `var`.

Edit: I'm not sure what you did, but I fixed your fiddle with this code:

```
var current;
function genSine(val1, val2) {

    var freq = 0.1; // angular frequency

   var coords = function(x, y) {
        var amplitude = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+10);
        var phase = Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+10);
        return {
            x : Math.sin(freq * (val1 + phase) * amplitude) + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1),
            y : Math.sin(freq * (val2 + phase) * amplitude) + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
        };
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        current = coords(50, 50);
        console.log(current);
        $(".display").html(JSON.stringify(current));
    }, 500);
}

genSine(10, 20);

setInterval(function() {
    $(".display2").html("d2:"+JSON.stringify(current));
}, 200);
```

Comment: I went ahead and did that but now current always = {}, so current.x is always undefined.  I'll continue to tinker, thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg: Hmm. It's working fine for me. Check the code I edited in above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post.  For some reason it doesn't fire on the first try but works afterwards but that is a different issue.  Marking as solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your `current` is fine in that scope, it is your `coords` function that is not in the right scope. Put that in the global scope together with the `freq` variable:

```
var freq = 0.1; // angular frequency
var coords = function (x, y) {
    var amplitude = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var phase = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    return {
        x: Math.sin(freq * (val1 + phase) * amplitude) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
        y: Math.sin(freq * (val2 + phase) * amplitude) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
    };
}

function genSine(val1, val2) {

    setInterval(function () {
        current = coords(50, 50);
        console.log('Val 1: ' + current.x);
        console.log('Val 2: ' + current.y);
    }, 2000);
}

genSine(10, 20);
```

Comment: "Your `current` is fine in that scope" – no, it is not. It is an implicit global. That is bad practice. Put that code in strict mode and watch it break.

Comment: Why? It is only used within the setInterval function.

Comment: Cluttering the global space is always bad, but implicit globals are a thing on their own, because even scoping the code won't fix it. No variable should ever be declared without `var`. You risk breaking other code as well as making your code hard to maintain and debug. It's a small script – but it always starts with small scripts.

Comment: Here is a fun story on that particular topic if you don't believe one `var` can really make that much of a difference: http://blog.safeshepherd.com/23/

Answer (score 0):

in typescript i did following code. in the below code i assign **_this** with the value of **this**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number = 22.008515;
  setMarker(){
   console.log('Inside setMarker Lat : '+this.lat); // 22.008515
    var _this = this;
    setInterval(function() {
     console.log('Inside setInterval this.lat : '+this.lat); // undefined
     console.log('Inside setInterval _this.lat : '+_this.lat); // 22.008515
    }, 8000)
  }
}
```